# Transformation rules to distinguish common variable with Subscript and OverBar $x,x^2,\bar{x},\bar{x}^2, x_p,x_p^2, \bar{x}_p, \bar{x}^2_p $

Tags: pattern-matching

I am looking for help in writing transformation rules in which I wish to distinguish between eight variables $x,x^2,\bar{x},\bar{x}^2, x_p,x_p^2, \bar{x}_p,\bar{x}^2_p $.

For each of these eight variables, I would like eight separate transformation rules such that  :

$x,x^2,\bar{x},\bar{x}^2, x_p,x_p^2, \bar{x}_p,  \bar{x}^2_p \rightarrow 
     (\bar{x}+\tilde{x}),(\bar{x}+\tilde{x})^2,(\bar{x}+\tilde{x}),(\bar{x}+\tilde{x})^2, (\bar{x}_p+\tilde{x}_p),(\bar{x}_p  + \tilde{x}_p)^2, (\bar{x}_p+\tilde{x}_p),  (\bar{x} + \tilde{x}_p)^2  $

I am having considerable trouble defining the correct constraints so that each of the transformation rules only activates for its corresponding variable.
I have had some partial success, for example rule six for $x^2_p$:

```
rule6 := { Power[Subscript[x, p], power_] -> Power[Subscript[OverBar[x], p] + Subscript[OverTilde[x], p], power]}
```

when applied to the expression:

$x^2 x_p^2 y_p^2 \bar{x}_p^2\text{/.}\, \text{rule6}$

which in code is:

`Times[Power[x,2],Power[Subscript[x,p],2],Power[Subscript[y,p],2],Power[Subscript[OverBar[x],p],2]] /. rule6`

yields the desired output $x^2 y_p^2 \bar{x}_p^2 \left(\bar{x}_p+\tilde{x}_p\right){}^2$.

Similarly, rule two for $x^2$

```
rule2 := { Power[x, power_] -> Power[OverBar[x] + OverTilde[x], power]}
```

when applied to expression

$x^2 x_p^2 y_p^2 \bar{x}_p^2\text{/.}\, \text{rule2}$

which in code is

`Times[Power[x,2],Power[Subscript[x,p],2],Power[Subscript[y,p],2],Power[Subscript[OverBar[x],p],2]] /. rule2`

yields the desired output $x_p^2 y_p^2 \left(\bar{x}+\tilde{x}\right)^2 \bar{x}_p^2$.

However, I am having particular trouble defining a proper rule for $x$.

My attempt

`rule1 := {var_ /; var === x -> (OverBar[var] + OverTilde[x])}`

is too permissive, in that it matches the $x$ even when it appears with a Subscript, with a Power, or with an OverBar.

For example, when applied to the expression

$x^2 x_p^2 y_p^2 \bar{x}_p^2\text{/.}\, \text{rule1}$

which in code is

`Times[Power[x,2],Power[Subscript[x,p],2],Power[Subscript[y,p],2],Power[Subscript[OverBar[x],p],2]] /. rule1`

it yields the incorrect output $y_p^2 \left(\bar{x}+\tilde{x}\right)^2 \overline{\bar{x}+\tilde{x}}_p^2 \left(\bar{x}+\tilde{x}_p\right){}^2$; the correct output in this case would have been to leave the input untouched: $x^2 x_p^2 y_p^2 \bar{x}_p^2$.

Similarly, when applied to the expression

$x x_p y_p \bar{x}_p \text{/.}\, \text{rule1}$

which in code is

`Times[x,Subscript[x,p],Subscript[y,p],Subscript[OverBar[x],p]] /. rule1`

it yields the incorrect output $y_p \left(\bar{x}+\tilde{x}\right) \overline{\bar{x}+\tilde{x}}_p \left(\bar{x}+\tilde{x}_p\right)$; the correct output would have been $(\bar{x} + \tilde{x}) x_p y_p \bar{x}_p$.

How do I force the pattern matching to ignore the OverBar, Power and Subscript cases?

I have tried things such as
`rule1ALT :=   var_ /; var === x && FreeQ[{Subscript, OverBar, Power}, Head[var]] ->    OverBar[x] + OverTilde[x]`

but the problem seems to be that Head[var] returns Symbol and not the OverBar, Subscript or Power encompassing it.

Comment: I'd like to point out that, if you are going to do any calculations on these variables, you are definitely asking for trouble when using formatting expressions such as `Subscript` etc in variable names. See e.g. this FAQ on ["Basic syntax issues"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/27951). If, on the other hand, you are only interested in typographical layout, then *Mathematica* might honestly not be the most straightforward method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The real reason why this is not working is that Mathematica actually matches each `x` inside `Subscript` and `OverBar` individually.
In other words, `OverBar[x]` doesn't match your rule, but the internal `x` *individually* matches the rule when `ReplaceAll` goes to a deeper level in the expression.

To solve this problem, you can use the `LevelSpec` option of the `Replace` function to avoid matching on deeper levels.
Using the same definition for your `rule1ALT`, you can do:

```
Replace[Times[x, Subscript[x, p], Subscript[y, p], 
  Subscript[OverBar[x], p]], rule1ALT, 1]
```

Which yields the correct desired output: $(\bar{x} + \tilde{x}) x_p y_p \bar{x}_p$.

**However**, this is not a universal solution! It will not work if you have the `OverBar` and `Subscript` symbols appearing in many different levels of the expression, which most probably you will. After all, there is no way to distinguish `x` inside `x^2` from `x` inside `OverBar[x]` if you traverse an expression hierarchically on all levels.

The best *workaround* in my opinion is to actually change the name of the variables, so that `ReplaceAll` can work on them seamlessly on all levels, and only substitute the names at the end of calculation. For example, set `y` to be `OverBar[x]` and `z` to be `x_p`, go through your manipulations, then at the end of each calculation before displaying the results, do `/. {y -> OverBar[x], z->x_p}`

Answer (score 2):

As in a previous answer to a similar [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/170921/45431), I like to use multiple replacement rules to avoid replacing "avoided" patterns. In your example, I would do:

```
xRule = {
    s:(Subscript|Power|OverBar)[__] -> s, (* pattern to avoid *)
    x -> OverBar[x] + OverTilde[x]
};
```

Your first example:

```
ReplaceAll[
    x^2 Subscript[x,p]^2 Subscript[y,p]^2 Subscript[OverBar[x],p]^2,
    xRule
] //TeXForm
```

> $x^2 x_p^2 y_p^2 \bar{x}_p^2$

And your second example:

```
ReplaceAll[
    x Subscript[x,p] Subscript[y,p] Subscript[OverBar[x],p],
    xRule
] //TeXForm
```

> $x_p y_p \left(\bar{x}+\tilde{x}\right) \bar{x}_p$